# How to handle special characters in HTML?

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing, elementtree

I'm using Python `requests` library to make get & post requests and then I parse the response using ElementTree as follows:

```
etree.HTML(response.text)
```

In some cases, I receive the following text in response which has some special characters highlighter in bold:

```
Hooverâ€™s Inc., a D&amp;B Company puts you on the fastest path to business.                Â© 2012 Hoover's Inc, Inc. All rights reserved.
```

This is creating problems for me and `etree.HTML(response.text)` method returns `None` if there are special characters in response text like above and due to this, I'm unable to get required information using `etree.xpath()` method.

Also, If I try to replace the above text which has special characters with empty string(''), I get the following compile time exception:

```
Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file E:\abc\xyz.py on line 50, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I've also tried to encode the response text in `ISO-8859-1` but all in vain.
Please help to get me out of this trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the result of UTF-8 bytes being mis-interpreted as Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1). You should, however, not pass Unicode to the ElementTree API in the first place.

Use the `response.content` attribute instead; `.text` gives you decoded values (and in this case, incorrectly decoded):

```
etree.HTML(response.content)
```